# Hibernate 5.3+ using hibernateLazyInitializer causes javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find entity.Person

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss7.x, hibernate-envers, lazy-initialization

Having a problem with upgrading hibernate to 5.3+ with the method calling `getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier()` on a `HibernateProxy` which is loaded with `AuditedReader` from hibernate envers.

The following example is what I have in code:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name="country_id", foreignKey = 
@javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name="FK_country_id"))
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Country country;
}

@Entity
@Audited
public class Country {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(name="countryName")
    public String countryName;
}


/// Code in another class which I want to get the ID of the country from the Person that comes from the Audited Table of hibernate envers
/// The field is a reflection of which variable it needs to get out of the object
/// field = "country" which needs to get from the personObject
private static Object getId(Object personObject, Field field) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Object countryObject = field.get(value);
    if (object instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        return ((HibernateProxy)countryObject).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The stacktrace which I get using the code is:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find entity.Country with id 10
    at org.hibernate@5.3.29.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.29.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:291)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.29.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:186)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.29.Final-redhat-00001//org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getIdentifier(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:95)
```

The entry of the country is in the database so it exist, also when I debug with Intellij and evaluate the `((HibernateProxy)countryObject).getHibernateLazyInitializer()`, it will return the object but if I let it run without debug I'll get `EntityNotFoundException`.

Already spended hours to figure how to fix it, even upgrading hibernate to a higher version but it doesn't seems to fix it. Someone knows in which direction or solution I can look at.

Thanks

PS: We are using the JBoss 7.4 EAP with patch 11, so using all of their dependencies (the important usage for this code is `hibernate-core-5.3.29.Final-redhat-00001` and `hibernate-envers-5.3.28.Final-redhat-000015.3.28.Final-redhat-00001` also using `javax.persistence.api`).

Answer (score 1):

Today I have solved the issue, We went from hibernate 3.x to hibernate 5.x and there was a change in the `((HibernateProxy)countryObject).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getIdentifier()`. The hibernate 3.x returns directly the id of the object but in hibernate 5.x when you call this method it will initialize the object which cause the not found exception.

```
// from org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer hibernate 5.x
@Override
public final Serializable getIdentifier() {
    if ( isUninitialized() && isInitializeProxyWhenAccessingIdentifier() ) {
        initialize(); // <-- this causes the entity not found exception
    }
    return id;
}
```

So to fix this we used
`((HibernateProxy)countryObject).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getInternalIdentifier()` which only returns the id and not initialize the object because we only needed the Id.